# Incorrect output from cp, rm, and so on

Tags: command-line, character-encoding, putty

When I run, say, `cp`, I get output like the following:

```
# cp -v Foo Bar
âFooâ -> âBarâ
```

What's up with the weird `â` characters? Why is the shell doing this? It looks like some kind of strange encoding issue.

When I use PuTTY, I get `â`. When I log into the actual machine locally, I get `?` in inverse-video. If I redirect `stdout` to a file, copy that to my Windows machine, and open it, I get some random combination of characters until I tell me text editor to pretend the file is UTF-8. And then I get propper open- and close-quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an encoding issue.

Set your Putty character set translation to "`UTF-8`":

```
Window -> Translation -> Remote character set
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the PuTTY issue, change the Settings under Window -> Translation and select (or manually enter if not present) "utf-8"

Which shell are you using on the machine?

Comment: Just the default Bash shell. This is a default install of OpenSUSE, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work logging in locally. (PuTTY is another matter, obviously.)